# Disabling scrolling after specific child

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

In my case, I have a `HorizontalScrollView`. What I need to achieve is that `HorizontalScrollView` should be scollable until a specific child. (By child I mean view lying inside `HorizontalScrollView`.) User should not be able to scroll the rest of it. My current minimum SDK is 21. So that I cannot use `HorizontalScrollView.setOnScrollChange()` method. It is available for API level 23+.

Searched the net for some time but could not find solutions suitable for my case.

How can I achieve this? Any suggestions would greatly help.

The reason for doing this is to achieve an affect where `scrollbar` stops from scrolling at a specified location. See the picture below. 
[image]

Comment: why do you add those extra elements which should not scroll

Comment: In my case user should not be able to scroll to econom class while he is pruchasing business class or vice verse. So i need to limit him to only see business class. Reason for adding the full children is that full children (that is econom + business) should make up the full `scrollbar`.

Comment: Only add what the user needs to see. If he cannot see it (i.e. by restricting scrolling to it) there is no reason at all to add it in the first place. Please specify what you mean by "should make up the full scrollbar"? Why when you want to restrict scrolling to it?

Comment: @RafaelT totally agree with you on that. But this is the requirement my client has. What I mean is: If only business layout is visible and other children are hidden, `scrollBar` at the bottom will be adjusted to this width right? If business + econom are shown, `scrollbar` width will be longer. What I need is the scrollbar `track` should be only scrollable untill the child I specify. Both scrolling and scrollbar `track` should stop.

Comment: Depends on what you define the `ScrollView` width. if its `match_parent` it will fill up the width. Showing a ScrollBar, stopping it somewhere in the middle with no possibility to get over it would be considered a bug by me and other users. I would assume that the app hangs in some strange way. So even If you had an `OnScrollChangeListener` it would be weired to scroll, and then set back to your predefined item. What about showing them in a `disabled`state, like greying them out and make the unclickable if the *need* to get shown?

Comment: modifed the question, for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @RafaelT this is what i actually suggested to client. But they want something as shown in above picture. They just want to DISABLE scrolling. Now, I am just stuck here ))

Comment: so tell em its not possible in API 21. Or "fake" it by making a scroll View fill up half the width, and adding other elements static to its right

Comment: @RafaelT yeah at the end of the day I think I am gonna end with your suggestion. But could you please take your time and explain in details what do you mean by faking it? How can i fake it? I did not really get "scrollView fill up the half width..." part.

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of fake the sugested behaviour by adding a ScrollView which fills up half the screen and adding static elements right next to it.

below is a pseudo layout on how it can be done:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000">

            <!-- Scrollable Items here -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="item1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="item2"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="item3"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="item4"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="item5"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="item6"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#00FF00">
        <!-- Unscrollable Items here -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="item1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="item2"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the important part is `weightSum=1` and the `layout_weights` of `.5` with a respective `width` of `0` . You can adjust them to your needs of course.

Comment: tried your suggestion, but could not achieve what i wanted.